# Conditions on a matrix such that its powers should have $0$ on the diagonal

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

How can we find sufficient conditions in order for the powers $A^k$ of a square matrix $A \in M_n (\Bbb Z_2)$ with $0$ on the diagonal should also have $0$ on the diagonal?

Comment: It's not true that if $A$ is a square matrix with zero diagonal entries then $A^k$ has zero diagonal entries for every $k$. Take $$\left( \begin{array}{lr} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) $$ as an example.

Comment: I know its not true for every matrix. My question is can we figure it out form the original matrix that the A^k will have zero diagonal entries.

Comment: Are the entries real, complex, or elements of some other field?

Comment: Binary 0 or 1..

Answer (score 1):

The question is not too clear. If you only want an example then consider the follow:
Let us look at the strictly upper triangluar matrix (with all zero entries below and including the diagonal)
\begin{align}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & \ldots & 1 &1\\
0& 0 & 1 &\dots & 1 \\
\vdots & \ldots & \ddots & 1 & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ldots & \ddots & 0 & 1\\
0 & \dots & \ldots & \ldots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Then we see $A^2, A^3$ and so on will have zero entries on the diagonal.